# Error:not a statement (Query)

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm new to android and now trying to use `cursor` to retrieve data from `SQLite`. How to fix my `selectQuery`?

```
  List<Info> info=new ArrayList<Info>();
        String selectQuery=("SELECT Weather, Date, Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " WHERE Name = ?",new String{}(String.valueOf(name)));
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
```

**Error**

```
Error:(77, 142) error: ')' expected
Error:(77, 143) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(77, 147) error: not a statement
Error:(77, 153) error: ';' expected
Error:(77, 177) error: ';' expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is due of your String select query. You have a comma in the middle which doesn't make any sense. The concatenation operator is `+` and you have not the `,`

this

```
 String selectQuery=("SELECT Weather, Date, Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " WHERE Name = ?",new String{}(String.valueOf(name)))
```

should be

```
  String selectQuery="SELECT Weather, Date, Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " WHERE Name = ?";
```

and then you want the selectionArgs:

```
 String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(name)};
```

and then rawQuery:

```
database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQuery,selectionArgs);
```